# Is there a way to enable/disable the exception handling in the C++ source file

Tags: c++, gcc

I know C++ compiler allows to use `-fexceptions` and `-fno-exceptions` to enable and disable exception handling. Is there a way to disable or enable exception handling by just defining some preprocessor in the C++ source code file?

Comment: No. Standard C++ requires exceptions to be enabled anyway.

Comment: What do you expect `-fno-exceptions` to do? Hint: calling code actually throwing exceptions from code compiled with `-fno-exceptions` will just break.

Comment: @VoidStar: That's not even an appropriate statement, since the C++ standard has no concept of "enabling". It's simply the case that C++ contains exceptions as part of the language.

Comment: Just do not use `try` clause, etc.

Comment: @Kerrek: Semantics, it requires them to work and to be handled appropriately, so not having this enabled would be nonstandard.

Comment: State your compiler.

Comment: @Olaf: Insufficient.

Comment: @VoidStar: When we discuss C++ language requirements, yes, we are talking about semantics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Why that? The question was "how to disable exception **handling** in the source file" (not infrastructure). There was no point about disabling in the whole program :-) (or if it should actually make sense - I doubt if the question itself does)

Comment: @Olaf: Eh? No, my point is, "just do not use `try` clause" is not even remotely the same as removing exception support from the functions defined in a source file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You might have overlooked the "etc.". I did not want to imply you can just turn it on or off by a compiler switch. I'm very well aware there is much more and once you use the excception handling statements (which does include **all** libraries, of course!), etc., you cannot simply turn them off by a compiler switch or pragma.

Comment: @Olaf: You suggested that you can turn it off simply by not using it! I think then that your initial comment was very misleading if that's not what you meant.

Answer (score 8):

The same question was recently asked on a mailing list: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.help/48303

The answer is that you can do this:

```
#GCC pragma optimize "no-exceptions"
```

Now, whether you *should* do this is another matter, but suffice to say that you'd better know what you're doing if you go down this path.